# Is there a way to connect directly to postgres from appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine, heroku-postgres

On Heroku it says that "Apps can connect to Heroku Postgres from Heroku, Google App Engine,...", but how is that possible if App Engine only allows http connections?

Comment: app engine only allow http but you talk about connect to heroku but app engine.

Comment: I doubt that is possible

Answer (score 2):

App Engine recently added support for Sockets, see:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/

Thus is should be possible to use either a pure-Python or pure-Java Postgres client to connect to a Postgres instance.